# comparing the content and produce new file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed, perl

I have two files containing content like the following:

```
File 1

OG5_126568
OG5_126583
OG5_126593
OG5_126596
OG5_126599
OG5_126609

File2

OG5_126568  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813339.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_040642027.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_028858051.1
OG5_126585  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt    WP_058023688.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_021814787.1
```

I want to compare my first file with the second file and produce a new file contains only matched content.

```
produced file

    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt WP_021814787.1
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_021814787.1
```

which command I should use?

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect `OG5_126568  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_040642027.1` in the output? That line does not appear in the input. Same is true for the line `OG5_126593  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_021814787.1`. It doesn't appear in the input either.

Comment: Because I need this. I want to get output like above (as shown in pic).

Comment: In the pic there are thirty different 2nd column and it compares the OG5 number and in output, it shows that kind of thing.

Comment: From _"Because I need this"_ I cannot figure out where the line `OG5_126568  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_040642027.1` in the output comes from. That line ***does not exist in the input***.

Comment: After your edit I wonder why the line `OG5_126568  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813339.1` doesn't appear in the output although the number `OG5_126568` is in 1.txt.

Comment: @ArslanTariq I think that my reply now works https://askubuntu.com/a/1124822/796708

Comment: *Because I need this* <-- instant top in my favourite comments list.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can be supplied with a *file* that contains the patterns to search for:

```
$ grep -f 1.txt 2.txt
OG5_126568  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813339.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_040642027.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
```

This will print every line from `2.txt` that contain any of the patterns
given in `1.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I update my question, please check it, it will be helpful for clarification of the question.

Comment: @ArslanTariq Sorry, but that command exactly does what you described in your question. It compares every line from `1.txt` to every line from `2.txt` and prints those lines from `2.txt` that have a match. In other words, it prints every line from `2.txt` that contain `OG5_126568` or contain `OG5_126583` or contain `OG5_126593` etc. If that is not what you want, please update your question.

Comment: That should have worked and is really the best solution if the first file isn't too big.

Comment: I have updated my question.
It should compare 1.txt with 2.txt to every line and only prints those lines which exactly match.
like OG5_126568 is present is psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt but it is not present in psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt so it should not be printed.
OG5_126593 present in every *.txt so it should be printed.

Comment: So you want to print all the key-txtfile-WP from file2 if 1) "key" appears for all possible txtfile and 2) key is in file1?

Comment: @xenoid yeah want exactly that thing

Answer (score 1):

If the files are both sorted on the first column, use the `join` command:

```
join file1 file2
```

Comment: Nice. In case the files are not sorted, write `join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` instead to sort them ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I have edited my reply, I think I have understood the question.

with [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) (here the latest Linux binary https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/download/5.4.0/mlr.linux.x86_64) you can start to collect the number of files

```
mlr --nidx --fs ' ' --repifs cut -f 2 then uniq -a 2.txt | wc -l >./filesnumber.txt
```

They are 3:

```
psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt
psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt
psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt
```

Then you can collect the distinct couples of occurrences with

```
mlr --nidx --fs ' ' --repifs cut -f 1,2 then uniq -a 2.txt >./distinctValues.txt
```

These are

```
OG5_126568 psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt
OG5_126583 psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt
OG5_126583 psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt
OG5_126585 psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt
```

Then you can filter only the record in which for field 1 there is a distinct values count of 3

```
mlr --nidx --ifs ' ' --repifs cut -f 1 then count-distinct -f 1 \
then filter '$count=='"$(cat filesnumber.txt)"'' \
then cut -f 1 distinctValues.txt >./okValue.txt
```

It gives you, what you want: `OG5_126593`.

And at the end you can apply the join

```
mlr --nidx --fs ' ' --repifs join -j 1 -f okValue.txt 2.txt
```

That gives you back

```
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593 psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt WP_021814787.1
```

I have used these two input files

```
OG5_126568
OG5_126583
OG5_126593
OG5_126596
OG5_126599
OG5_126609


OG5_126568  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813339.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_040642027.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_028858051.1
OG5_126585  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt    WP_058023688.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_021814787.1
```

Comment: @arslan-tariq I think I have understood your question. Above you have my reply

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below command (assuming the first file is `1.txt`, second file is `2.txt`):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} a[$1] ' 1.txt 2.txt 
OG5_126568  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813339.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_040642027.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
```

Note that at your expected output the following line:

```
OG5_126568  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_040642027.1
```

Seems to be:

```
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_040642027.1
```

Comment: What does the awk code mean, how does it work?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.
I update my question, please check it, it will be helpful for clarification of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I have updated my question. It should compare 1.txt with 2.txt to every line and only prints those lines which exactly match. like OG5_126568 is present is psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt but it is not present in psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt so it should not be printed. OG5_126593 present in every *.txt so it should be printed.

I would look at this differently:

1. You have N different `*.txt` files. N can be obtained by:

   ```
   N=$(awk '{print $2}' <file2 | sort | uniq | wc -l)
   ```
2. If a key must appear in all `*.txt` files, then for such a key you should find N **different** key-txt pairs (independently of the WP-* parts). This number can be obtained like this for each key:

   ```
   awk '{print $1 " " $2}' <file2 | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c
   ```

   so the keys that occur N times are obtained by:

   ```
   awk '{print $1 " " $2}' <file2 | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | grep -E "^\s+$N" | awk '{print $2}'
   ```
3. You then use this list of keys to filter `file2` using `join` or `grep -f`, and if necessary filter this again using `file1` to make sure you only have keys from `file1` (but I suspect that `file1` may not be necessary).

Comment: @perlduck Yes, fixed

Comment: sorry I can't understand.

Comment: can you simple write the commands instead of text.

Comment: AskUbuntu (and any other StackExchanged site) isn't a script-writing service. Your problem is somewhat easy if you look at it from the right point of view (different from yours, but with the same results). Editing the answer to make it clearer....